# How can I classify different images with various sizes and formats in scikit-learn?

Tags: image, numpy, matplotlib, scikit-learn, classification

I'm trying to build a simple image classifier using scikit-learn. I'm hoping to avoid having to resize and convert each image before training.

#### Question

Given two different images that are different formats and sizes (`1.jpg` and `2.png`), how can I avoid a `ValueError` while fitting the model?

- I have one example where I train using only `1.jpg`, which fits successfully.
- I have another example where I train using both `1.jpg` and `2.png` and a `ValueError` is produced.

#### This example will fit successfully:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn import svm 
import matplotlib.image as mpimg

target = [1, 2]
images = np.array([
    # target 1
    [mpimg.imread('./1.jpg'), mpimg.imread('./1.jpg')],
    # target 2
    [mpimg.imread('./1.jpg'), mpimg.imread('./1.jpg')],
])
n_samples = len(images)
data = images.reshape((n_samples, -1))
model = svm.SVC()
model.fit(data, target)
```

#### This example will raise a Value error.

Observe the different 2.png image in target 2.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn import svm 
import matplotlib.image as mpimg

target = [1, 2]
images = np.array([
    # target 1
    [mpimg.imread('./1.jpg'), mpimg.imread('./1.jpg')],
    # target 2
    [mpimg.imread('./2.png'), mpimg.imread('./1.jpg')],
])
n_samples = len(images)
data = images.reshape((n_samples, -1))
model = svm.SVC()
model.fit(data, target)
# ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

#### 1.jpg

[image: 1.jpg]

#### 2.png

[image: 2.png]

Comment: yes, the error is reasonable. you cannot train on different dimensions and then test/predict on others. Have you tried downscaling? You can Downscale all the images to the same size and then do any machine learning

Comment: Would it be inappropriate if I post a link of my stackexchange question here ?

Comment: It would be fine if it streamlines solving this problem! Thanks.

Comment: Ok so I'm not posting as it belongs to text classification and it's more like asking advice sort of question. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this, I would really recommend using the tools in `Keras` that are specifically designed to preprocess images in a highly scalable and efficient way.

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
```

## 1 Determine the target size of your new pictures

```
h,w = 150,150 # desired height and width
batch_size = 32 
N_images = 100 #total number of images
```

`Keras` works in batches, so `batch_size` just determines how many pictures at once will be processed (this does not impact your end result, just the speed).

## 2 Create your Image Generator

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1./255)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    'Pictures_dir',
    target_size=(h, w),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode = 'binary')
```

The object that is going to do the image extraction is `ImageDataGenerator`. It has the method `flow_from_directory` which I believe might be useful for you here. It will read the content of the folder `Pictures_dir` and expect your images to be in folders by class (eg: Pictures_dir/class0 and Pictures_dir/class1). The generator, when called, will then create images from these folders and also import their label (in this example, 'class0' and 'class1').

There are plenty of other arguments to this generator, you can check them out in the `Keras` documentation (especially if you want to do data augmentation).

Note: this will take any image, be it PNG or JPG, as you requested

If you want to get the mapping from class names to label indices, do:

```
train_generator.class_indices
# {'class0': 0, 'class1': 1}
```

You can check what is going on with

```
plt.imshow(train_generator[0][0][0])
```

## 3 Extract all resized images from the Generator

Now you are ready to extract the images from the `ImageGenerator`:

```
def extract_images(generator, sample_count):
    images = np.zeros(shape=(sample_count, h, w, 3))
    labels = np.zeros(shape=(sample_count))
    i = 0
    for images_batch, labels_batch in generator: # we are looping over batches
        images[i*batch_size : (i+1)*batch_size] = images_batch
        labels[i*batch_size : (i+1)*batch_size] = labels_batch
        i += 1
        if i*batch_size >= sample_count:
            # we must break after every image has been seen once, because generators yield indifinitely in a loop
            break
    return images, labels

images, labels = extract_images(train_generator, N_images)

print(labels[0])
plt.imshow(images[0])
```

Now you have your images all at the same size in `images`, and their corresponding labels in `labels`, which you can then feed into any `scikit-learn` classifier of your choice.

Comment: Pretty nice way to load up images and resize them! Trying to figure out how to get these into a train_test_split and model.fit. It seems like sci-kit only deals with 2d arrays and images.shape is (N, 150, 150, 3). Thanks for your help!

Comment: @tester One way to do this is to flatten your (150,150,3) images into vectors. But yes, this is a limitation of scikit learn, which is not the ideal framework to train models for images.

Answer (score 1):

Its difficult because of the math operations behind the scene, (the details are out of scope) if you manage do so, lets say you build your own algorithm, still you would not get the desired result.
i had this issue once with faces with different sizes. maybe this piece of code give you starting point.

```
from PIL import Image
import face_recognition

def face_detected(file_address = None , prefix = 'detect_'):
    if file_address is None:
        raise FileNotFoundError('File address required')
    image = face_recognition.load_image_file(file_address)
    face_location = face_recognition.face_locations(image)

    if face_location:
        face_location = face_location[0]
        UP = int(face_location[0] - (face_location[2] - face_location[0]) / 2)
        DOWN = int(face_location[2] + (face_location[2] - face_location[0]) / 2)
        LEFT = int(face_location[3] - (face_location[3] - face_location[2]) / 2)
        RIGHT = int(face_location[1] + (face_location[3] - face_location[2]) / 2)

        if UP - DOWN is not LEFT - RIGHT:
            height = UP - DOWN
            width = LEFT - RIGHT
            delta = width - height
            LEFT -= int(delta / 2)
            RIGHT += int(delta / 2)

        pil_image = Image.fromarray(image[UP:DOWN, LEFT:RIGHT, :])
        pil_image.thumbnail((50, 50), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        pil_image.save(prefix + file_address)

        return True

    pil_image = Image.fromarray(image)
    pil_image.thumbnail((200, 200), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    pil_image.save(prefix + file_address)
    return False
```

Note : i wrote this long time ago maybe not a good practice

Comment: You inspired me to just make a PIL resizer script: https://github.com/dancrew32/image_shape_normalizer. I just convert all images to RGB and force them to fit 100x100px in size. This makes all of the numpy.array shapes (100, 100, 3). See any downsides to this? Thanks for the inspiration

Comment: Actually struggled to get the right shape for these images... Found this repo that is a pretty great workflow for scanning a directory of directories that make up the labels and data: https://github.com/whimian/SVM-Image-Classification/blob/master/Image%20Classification%20using%20scikit-learn.ipynb these images are not all identical, which is exciting.