# Creating image dataset from folder in Keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am pretty new to Keras/Tensorflow and I am trying to use Keras for a face classification task where each person is in a folder, I have been using Pytorch and there is torchvision.datasets.ImageFolder and dataloader to create a dataset with transformations and to create a data loader specifying batchsize etc. Is there a way to do the same with Keras and Tensorflow, I know there is Data API, but I have been having some trouble how to do the same with using that.

Any help is appreciated thank you

Edit I tried to follow the exact same thing as [loading data guide with tf.data here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/images) but I got an error saying the input had dimensions (none,none,none,3)

Comment: I believe you might find this useful? Let me know if not 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56718952/how-can-i-classify-different-images-with-various-sizes-and-formats-in-scikit-lea/56821884#56821884

Answer (score 0):

Have a look the examples here: https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/